# Как по клику на кнопку изменить чекбоксы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как по клику на кнопку перенести `checked=""` во второй `input`? Т.е из первого удалить `checked`, а во второй добавить.

```
<input name="allow_main" value="1" type="checkbox" checked="">
<input name="disable_index" value="1" type="checkbox">
<a href="#">кнопка</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('a').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('[name="allow_main"]').checked = false;
  document.querySelector('[name="disable_index"]').checked = true;

};
```

```html
<input name="allow_main" value="1" type="checkbox" checked="">
<input name="disable_index" value="1" type="checkbox">
<a href="#">кнопка</a>
```

Comment: А с `name=` никак не получится сделать? только класс добавлять?

Comment: @steep использовать можно любые css селекторы